# index.HTML does not recognize script in folder (chrome)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, phaser-framework

I am creating a browser based game with phaser, which involves linking to an external javascript file with my own code in it. For some reason when I use either

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/main.js"></script>` or

`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>`

to link the javascript to the HTML, no 404 is thrown but the script does not run. However, if I move main.js to the root directory and put

`<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>`

in the exact same spot, the script runs fine. Any theories as to why this is? I am using chrome version 57.0.2987.133. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The script is located in `pwd`, not `/js/` directory

Comment: I should mention I am running a python simpleHTTPServer from the root directory and accessing it via localhost:8000 in the browser, if this changes anything.

Comment: Have you tried setting full path to resource at `src`? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079/absolute-vs-relative-urls/21828923#21828923

Comment: Anything in the console?

Comment: Nothing in the console. It gives a 404 if I put in an incorrect url, but the console is totally silent with the correct URL, even with the use of console.log statements in the script

Comment: What's the full path of the 404?

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

`<script src="./js/main.js"></script>`

You had a simple scoping error and forgot the script's src.